# iOS 'Triple-click the Home button' conflicts when using both 'guided access' and MFi hearing aids

Tags: ios, mfi, guided-access

I'm developing an iOS app for 'Made for iPhone' hearing aid devices. The app is supposed to run in 'guided access' mode. To enter/exit this mode, one has to "Triple-click the Home button." (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612)

[image]

Unfortunately, that exact same shortcut is used to enter the MFi hearing aid options screen:

[image]

[Edit: When triple-clicking the Home button, only the hearing aid options appear and so it's not possible to enter the guided mode.]

So it seems, that Apple decided to not support the guided access mode for people using MFi hearing aids.

Is there any chance to customize any of these two hardware button actions?

Comment: What happens when you triple-click with your app? Which setting wins - MFi Hearing Aids or Guided Access? What did Apple say when you contacted them?

Comment: @RoboticCat I updated my question with info on 'which setting wins'. I did not contact Apple on that issue, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The only way you will be able to activate guided access in this situation is to manually turn it on using assistive touch > accessibility > guided access. Assistive touch needs to be enabled of course with guided access enabled for assistive touch. Hope this helps.